# SAS-Selecting Top Subjects- each with multiple rows

Tags: sorting, sas, grouping

I am trying to select the top 10 out of 200 subjects, each subject can have multiple rows and each subject is uniquely identified by the ID variable.  The data is sorted on variables amount_paid (descending-dollar amount) selection_flag (ascending-either 1 or 2).  For instance the data looks like this currently, with roughly 200 unique IDs:

```
ID   amount_paid   selection_flag   group
191  $10               1            R3  
101  $5                2            R2   
101  $3                2            R1 
750  $2                2            R0
250  $1                2            R0
```

I have tried selecting distinct IDs, assigning an enumeration, merging back, and selecting only the ids that have a number equal to 10 or less.  For example:

```
ID   number
191  1
101  2
101  2
750  3
250  4

But using distinct changes the order of IDs:

    ID   number
    101  1
    101  1
    191  2
    250  3
    750  4
```

I have also tried the proc sql (outobs=10) but that just returns the top rows not the top IDs and all their related rows.

So ideally I wanted to select the top ten ids and all their respective rows of data, and keep the order of sorting by amount_paid (ascending) and selection_group (descending) intact.  Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

Sample code that has been tried:

Code to create universe (create selection flag because want all R3, R4, and R5s if in data:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.univ1 AS 
   SELECT distinct t1.*,
          /* Selection Flag */
            (case when group in ('R3','R4','R5') then 1 else 2 end) As selection_flag
      FROM RawData t1 Left Join Value_Cde_Excl t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
                              Left Join Cond_Cde_Excl t3 ON (t1.ID= t3.CH_ICN)
                              Left Join Diag_Excl t4 ON (t1.ID = t4.CH_ICN)
      WHERE t1.y BETWEEN 'R0' AND 'RZ' AND   
                  t1.ID NE t2.ID AND
                  t1.ID NE t3.ID AND
                  t1.ID NE t4.ID
    ORDER BY Selection_Flag,
              Amt_Paid DESC,
                  ID;
QUIT;    


Code to pull distinct ids (loses order):
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.sample AS 
   SELECT distinct ID
      FROM univ1;
QUIT;  

Code to put distinct ids in a macro (loses order):

/*Create a macro variable of all ICNs */
proc sql noprint;
select distinct ID
into :ID_LIST separated by ' ' 
from univ1;
quit;

code to select top 10 observations (keeps order, but has duplicated ids)
PROC SQL outobs=10;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.sample AS 
   SELECT ID
      FROM univ1;
QUIT;
```

Comment: What defines "top rows"?  If an ID has five rows each with 1 in x, does that count as one of the top rows (if x=5 is a top value)?

Comment: Joe, I should have clarified, top rows are first defined by dollar amount X and secondly by y.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've tried that didn't work? And expand the sample data to reflect your issues.

Comment: @Reeza, I have added some sample code, and modified data, thank you for helping, please let me know if you need anything else added

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Step 1: Save the current order of the dataset**

Create an index variable that defines the order it currently is in.

```
data ordered;
     set have;
     Order+1;
run;
```

Output:

```
ID   Order
191  1
101  2
101  3
750  4
250  5
```

You can now manipulate the data as you like without losing the original order.

**Step 2: Remove duplicate IDs**

You want to select the top 10 IDs, but want to remove the duplicates. Let's sort it by `ID` and `Order` to get all of the duplicate IDs together.

```
proc sort data=ordered
    by ID Order;
run;
```

Your dataset should look as such:

```
ID   Order
101  2
101  3
191  1
250  5
750  4
```

We want to keep the first observation for each ID. We can remove the duplicates in two ways: through a data step, or another `proc sort` statement with the `equals` option. We'll use another `proc sort` since it has the `dupout` option.

```
proc sort data=ordered
          out=ordered_nodupes
          dupout=dupes
          nodupkey
          equals;
    by ID;
run;
```

You should now have two datasets:

```
Ordered_NoDupes
ID   Order
101  2
191  1
250  5
750  4
__________
  Dupes
ID   Order
101  3
```

**Step 3: Sort back to the original order**

Finally, sort back to the original order, keeping only the first 10 observations.

```
proc sort data=ordered_nodupes
          out=Top_10_IDs(obs=10);
     by order;
run;
```

We now have our top 10 IDs:

```
ID   Order
191  1
101  2
750  4
250  5
```

**Step 4: Select only the top 10 IDs**

We'll use the `Top_10_IDs` dataset as a key to find all rows in the master dataset whose ID is one of the Top 10.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select *
        from have
        where ID IN(select ID from Top_10_IDs);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first 10 ID's + all the associated rows (based on ID) :

```
data want1 ;
  set univ1 ;
  by ID notsorted ;
  if first.ID then id_cnt + 1 ;
  if id_cnt <= 10 then output ;
run ;
```